# Laravel domPDF arabic characters generate PDF error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, arabic, dompdf

In my project, I want to extract a certain page into a PDF file. the page is mostly in the Arabic language.

I am using [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)
On the first try, there were no characters showing, only question marks instead.

After digging around, I found that I should add the following CSS to my blade page:

```
* { 
    font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; 
    direction: rtl;
}
```

now the Arabic letters are showing in the PDF but their order is inverted (ABC is CBA).
after another round of research, I found a solution somewhere that I should add the following into my `dompdf/dompdf/src/Renderer/Text.php` right before

```
if (strtolower($style->direction) == 'rtl') {
    preg_match_all('/./us', $text, $ar);
    $text = join('',array_reverse($ar[0]));
}

// this is added here to know where exactly i put this code
$this->_canvas->text($x, $y, $text
```

this works and inverts back the text as it should be, but now the letters are separated... (Arabic letters belonging to the same word are connected)

ex: البناء is showing as ‫ا ل ب ن ا ء

this is a known issue for this library that is still not resolved. one of the commentators suggested using the composer library `chehivskiy/i18n-arabic‬` and use it as `new \I18N_Arabic('Glyphs')`

But I keep getting a class not found error. this library does not have any namespaces.

can anyone help me to either find a library that works to transform Arabic HTML to PDF, or maybe try to find a way to fix this library for it to work, or perhaps suggest a way to use a composer non-Laravel library such as `chehivskiy/i18n-arabic‬` in a Laravel project.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me. I have used this with laravel 8 like this : 
**step 1:** Install latest version of "Ar-PHP" library using composer

```
composer require khaled.alshamaa/ar-php
```

**step 2:**  integrat the code mentioned above with controller method :

```
use PDF;
use ArPHP\I18N\Arabic;

class PurchaseController  extends Controller {

function GeneratePDF(){
        $reportHtml = view('pdf.purchase_pdf', [])->render();
        
        $arabic = new Arabic();
        $p = $arabic->arIdentify($reportHtml);

        for ($i = count($p)-1; $i >= 0; $i-=2) {
            $utf8ar = $arabic->utf8Glyphs(substr($reportHtml, $p[$i-1], $p[$i] - $p[$i-1]));
            $reportHtml = substr_replace($reportHtml, $utf8ar, $p[$i-1], $p[$i] - $p[$i-1]);
        }

        $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($reportHtml);
        return $pdf->download('purchase.pdf');
}
}
```

**step 3:** download ["Amiri" font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amiri) and put *Amiri-Regular.ttf* and *Amiri-Bold.ttf* files in the fonts directory. 
Then add @font-face rules to the css of your view.blade.php in order to define the new custom font.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Your_custom_font_name";
    src: url("../fonts/Amiri-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Your_custom_font_name";
    src: url("../fonts/Amiri-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then set the font-family of your view.blade.php

```
body {
    font-family: "Your_custom_font_name";
}
```

That's it.
**Note:** To use Arabic digits instead of Hindo digits you can set *$hindo* parameter in the *Arabic.php* file to false :

```
public function utf8Glyphs($text, $max_chars = 50, $hindo = false, $forcertl = false) {
 ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright so what I did, I removed the composer library `chehivskiy/i18n-arabic‬` and downloaded [ar-php](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ar-php/) which is kind of the same but not throught composer.

I put the extracted `I18N` in the `app/Libraries` directory that I created.

Next i changed the name of `Arabic.php` into `I18N_Arabic.php` to be the same as the class name inside of it. Note that there is another class in that file `ArabicException` which i put in its own file.

I also added a namespace in that file `namespace App\Libraries\I18N;`

Next, since i'm using the `Glyph` class in `app\Libraries\I18N\Arabic\Glyphs.php`, i also did the same thing for it, changed its file name into `I18N_Arabic_Glyphs` to match the classname and added namespace `namespace App\Libraries\I18N\Arabic;`.

Next back in my `I18N_Arabic` class, replace the following:

```
$this->myClass = '\I18N_Arabic_' . $library;
$class         = '\I18N_Arabic_' . $library;
```

to

```
$this->myClass = 'App\Libraries\I18N\Arabic\I18N_Arabic_' . $library;
$class         = 'App\Libraries\I18N\Arabic\I18N_Arabic_' . $library;
```

and remove the following:

```
if (!$this->_useAutoload) {
    include self::getClassFile($this->myFile); 
}
```

Lastly, in the `vendor\dompdf\dompdf\src\Renderer\Text.php`, search for `$this->_canvas->text($x, $y, $text,` and put the following right before it:

```
$Arabic = new \App\Libraries\I18N\I18N_Arabic('Glyphs');
$text = $Arabic->utf8Glyphs($text);
```

and that's it. Now using the PDF class provided in the packages above will generate a pdf in Arabic with correct format.

Note that here i am using the `Glyph` class, if you are using another class from this library, you need to do all the above for the class as well