# I want to generate pdf using dompdf in laravel 8 with urdu/arabic language but its replacing with question marks like "????" @php @laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

my urdu/arabic text replacing with question mark letters

[here is pdf.blade.php file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM8J9.png)

[here is controller file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WunGr.png)

please help me if anyone has solution related this problem... thanks in advance.

I try it many more with different ways but not working for me I add font family, font face in html file

I want to generate urdu text pdf in laravel 8

Comment: Use a different PDF library that has better support for this type of font.

Comment: Please post your code as code, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Regarding the actual issue - does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462233/laravel-dompdf-arabic-characters-generate-pdf-error)?

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use PDF;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PDFController extends Controller
{
    public function Index(Request $request){
        return view('index');
    }

    public function GeneratePDF(Request $request){
        // return $pdf->stream();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf');
        return $pdf->download('urdu_testing.pdf');
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Use a package "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf".

Install with `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

Then use with :

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

...

public function generatePDF()
{
    $pdf = new Dompdf();
    $pdf->loadHtml('<h1>Urdu Text: یہ اردو متن ہے</h1>');
    $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    $pdf->render();
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Comment: I use this same above solution still not working even urdu printing with separating charechtors

Comment: @HafizAliAhmad give details, screenshot or anything

Comment: my controller and blade files screenshot is attached above links